# Word for not insignificant small talk?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, conversation

From Merriam Webster small talk is defined as 
"light or casual conversation"
However describing a conversation with my parents as small talk would indicate a shallow relationship. 
Is there a word that specifies "light or casual conversation to to meet social norms" vs "light or casual conversation to strengthen existing relationships" ?

Comment: I disagree that small talk indicates shallow conversation. Most relationships, even among married couples, begin with small talk.

Comment: "begin with small talk," I agree but once established "small talk" is not an appropriate description for a conversation. A husband and wife do not small talk, but this distinction is not in the definition of small talk. Thus I'm looking for better words

Comment: I think "phatic communication" describes the "social norms" variety of converstation.

Comment: How could you be strengthening a relationship by having light or casual conversation? Isn't a relationship strengthened when talking about serious topics and getting a feel for the innermost thoughts of someone else?

Comment: There's no reason why you couldn't, say, talk about the weather with your parents or your spouse. This type of conversation is still considered small talk even if you're close to each other. I think you need to clarify what "non insignificant small talk" means.

Comment: @Laurel A person's call to mother once a week or phone calls to old friends the conversation goes beyond "small talk" you would have with a stranger at a bus stop.  Sometimes you might actually have deep meaningful conversations of weight but more often it will be a more genuine "how are  you feeling" that actually expects a truthful answer ... "what is happening with your daughter's school" , "are you going to the same dentist?"  are your garden sprinklers working.  Signs of care specific to someone who's life you know.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest "visit"

It suggests a somewhat useful interchange and often an inquiry to communicate in a way that would allow to learn if a more important 'conversation' etc might be needed.

While visit can also mean travel to a place without human conversation the meanings below are common and involve and imply discussion that is either bond forming or light advice or exchange of knowledge from experiences etc.

**[visit from Oxford Living Dictionaries.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/visit)**
VERB visiting, visited, visits [WITH OBJECT]

> 1 Go to see and spend time with (someone) socially.
>
> ‘I came to visit my grandmother’
>
> no object ‘he went out to visit with his pals’
>
> ..
>
> 1.2 Go to see (someone or something) for a specific purpose, such as to give or receive professional advice.
>
> 1.3North American informal no object Chat.
> ‘there was nothing to do but visit with one another’